# comments_template() not showing posts. 320press

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am i am using [320press template.](http://320press.com/wpbs/)

I've noticed they use

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Which gives a nice little comment box,

---

[image]

---

Althought my problem is the comments will not show up above the box,

I did manage to get them to show up by using

```
<?php comments_template('/reviewcomments.php'); ?>
```

Although that seems to really mess up the css for it as you can see below.

---

[image]

---

> I would like to know is it possible to get the comments to show up but
>   keep the previous styling? Why is it that /reviewcomments.php messes
>   up the css?

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can get the comments to show without losing design by doing this,

```
<?php comments_template('',true); ?>
```